# JPA Query misunderstanding

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I use JPA (EclipseLink). I have entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {    
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;    
  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;    
  @Lob
  @Column(name = "data")
  byte[] bytes;
  //getters und setters are ommited
}
```

And I have such query

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyEntity m WHERE m.name = :name");
```

After I get result first time, `data` field in database changed. But when I run this query next times I still get old value. Can anybody explain me such behavior and show me a way how to get updated value

**UPD:** I call `query.getResultList()` and get instance of MyEntity. Then other application changes data in DB and commit it (I can run sql statement and I see it's really commited). Then I call `query.getResultList()` again and get instance of MyEntity that contains old data. My application uses transaction isolation level TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED. I've checked this by

```
Connection c = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
c.getTransactionIsolation();
```

**UPD2:** I've noticed that when I invoke the above statement `entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class)` the behavior is like cache cleared after this call. After this call I get updated instance by calling `query.getResultList()`. I'm totally confused about this.

Comment: You will need to show how the data changes and when (relative to your repeated queries), because your problem is probably related to transaction management. In other words: the change to your data probably hasn't been written to the database.

Comment: I just fixed a caching problem in my app. I am pretty sure you have the same issue. Review the JPA caching - helps a lot.

Comment: Do you call first and second query from inside the same entityManager or from 2 different entityManagers? Remember of cache Level 1 that is used implicitly.

Comment: From the same entityManager

Comment: So unless your UPD2 has a performance hit that is significant enough to impact your project, you've likely found your solution

Comment: I don't understand why this action entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class) results in clearing cache

Comment: If you really want to know, go into the EclipseLink sources (you can download them if they're not available in your IDE) and then debug the EntityManagerImpl class: there is an explicit check "if (cls.equals(java.sql.Connection.class))"

Answer (score 0):

Since there's another application changing the data, your cache is outdated. Therefore, your question is essentially a duplicate of: [EntityManager doesn't see changes made in other transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416359/entitymanager-doesnt-see-changes-made-in-other-transactions)

Please try the suggestions made in the accepted answer there, and see what that does for your problem.

EDIT: clearing the cache is usually vendor-dependent, so you'll have to search for documentation for your provider. For EclipseLink, this looks promising: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#How_to_refresh_the_cache

EDIT2: Since you use the EntityManager, you could try this directly:

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Please, read my second UPD, I'm just getting more confused

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want an entity to be cached you can try to mark it as not cacheable: @Cacheable(false)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@Cacheable(false)
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
```